# Which is more correct when translating the name "萧熏儿" to English. Is it "Xiao Xun Er", "Xiao Xun er", "Xiao Xun-er", "Xiao Xun'er", or "Xiao Xuner"?

Tags: translation

When translating the name of someone that has an "儿" in their name to English, which one is more correct?

Comment: What about "Xiao Xunr"? I often see 儿 transcribed as just a final -r rather than the full syllable -er.

Comment: Is this a question of the Chinese Language, or a question about English conventions of capitalisation of names?

Answer (score 5):

Except "Xiao Xun er", which does not seem to comply to English capitalization conventions for names, all of the others make sense.

If this is a real person born in P.R.C., then his/her passport would be "XIAO, XUNER". Therefore, this person's legal name will be "Xuner Xiao" in U.S.A. However, to help people pronounce it correctly, this person might decide to set a preferred first name as "Xun Er" or "Xun-er".

The standard way to write the name in pinyin would be "Xiāo Xūn'ér". This would be how it appears if this name shows up on some kids' reading book that has pronunciation annotations.

If you are translating any book, just make sure all names are translated consistently. "儿" is just a char that is pronounced "er".